# can anyone explain what mime type is this "application/json charset=utf-8" with space in between

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

Facing following **exception** while calling 3rd party service, I don't have the access on code to change the response content-type. I am not sure how to handle this.

*With soup-ui I have tested the service and it is working fine with the following content type, but in code I am getting the error.*

org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: **Invalid mime type "application/json charset=utf-8": Invalid token character ' ' in token "json charset=utf-8"**

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .build(); 

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
 

        WebClient client = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();    

        String body = "{***************************JSON*****************************}"; 

        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.post()
                .uri("https://***************/************************/inquiry")
                .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth("*********", "***********"))    
                .header("X-TIB-TransactionID", "23234234234234").header("X-TIB-***************", "*************")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .syncBody(body)                
                .retrieve(); 

        String response = responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

Comment: Assuming this is in a Content-Type header, it's missing a semi-colon. "application/json charset=utf-8" should be "application/json; charset=utf-8".

Comment: this is 3rd party service and we don't have any access on other side we just consume.

Comment: Given that the only question in your post is "can anyone explain" [...] the only real answer is "it's invalid". If you want more than that, you'll need to provide more context.

Comment: "but in code" - so what does that code look like? Have you been able to observe the raw HTTP response? (Note that just because *some* clients may be permissive with what they receive, that doesn't make it valid.)

Comment: No, I'm not going to chat. You still haven't indicated in the question whether you've observed the complete, raw HTTP request/response, and what's in there if so. Please think about everything *you'd* want to know if you a colleague asked you about this, and make sure you include all of that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have everything you need in the exception message: a whitespace is not supported in the mime type!

Check out the [MediaType](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) Spring class. It offers constants like [`APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE) to make your life easier!

The constant's value is: `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

That is the Mime Type you'd need to use.

Comment: Actually the issue is, its 3rd party service we are consuming and we don't have any access to change this.

Comment: @Abdul: I very nearly added a comment earlier - your question doesn't contain *any* context. All we know is "while getting the response" - not who's getting the response, or where from etc. Please edit your question to give *much* more information. Fundamentally if the third-party service is producing invalid HTTP responses, it would be a good idea to get them to fix it.